# How to return a column that links to 2 different tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Very new to SQL and I built a DB that stores information about companies. In the query below, I am trying to display the founder and ceo's name, but I am getting ambiguity errors.

I joined the founder table and ceo table onto the person table which stores the first and last name of the ceo/founder. The foreign key shared among all 3 tables is pid (person ID). I ran into issues with my select statement when I tried to return the names. I then tried adding the joined table name in from of the column name (founder.first_name and ceo.first_name), but that didn't work.

```
SELECT co.ein,
       company_name as Company,
       CONCAT(fo.first_name,' ',fo.last_name) as Founder,
       CONCAT(ceo.first_name,' ',ceo.last_name) as CEO,
       CASE
         WHEN last_price IS NULL THEN '-'
         ELSE CONCAT('$',FORMAT(last_price,2))
       END as 'Current Stock Price'
FROM company co
LEFT JOIN stock s ON co.ein = s.ein
LEFT JOIN ceo ON co.ein = ceo.ein
LEFT JOIN founder fo ON co.ein = fo.ein
LEFT JOIN person p ON ceo.pid = p.pid
LEFT JOIN person ON fo.pid = p.pid
```

I need to return the Company Name, Founder's Name, CEO's Name, and Current Stock Price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  two alias  for person  (eg: p1 and p2 )  and you shoudl use fully qualified  column name

```
SELECT co.ein,
       co.company_name as Company,
       CONCAT(fo.first_name,' ',fo.last_name) as Founder,
       CONCAT(ceo.first_name,' ',ceo.last_name) as CEO,
       CASE
         WHEN s.last_price IS NULL THEN '-'
         ELSE CONCAT('$',FORMAT(s.last_price,2))
       END as 'Current Stock Price'
FROM company co
LEFT JOIN stock s ON co.ein = s.ein
LEFT JOIN ceo ON co.ein = ceo.ein
LEFT JOIN founder fo ON co.ein = fo.ein
LEFT JOIN person p1 ON ceo.pid = p1.pid
LEFT JOIN person p2 ON fo.pid = p2.pid
```